# html tagging without effects

Tags: c#, .net

Example:

Input: `This is sample text` - this text is selected in textbox

Now I click button1 and:

Output: `<b>This is sample text</b>` - this is not bold. I want just raw html tags without effects.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace program1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = "http://url.com/";
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmldoc = web.Load(url);
            htmldoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;

            HtmlNode node = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h1[@class='class']");
            string title = node.InnerText;
            node = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='class2']");
            string content = node.InnerText;
            richTextBox1.Text = content;
            textBox2.Text = title;
        }
    }
}
```

*My language is not good then I drew what I mean.. but I need to 10 reputation to post images. Sorry.*

Comment: Are you outputting to a WinForm with a browser control, via Razor/MVC, ASP.NET? There isn't sufficient information here to help you out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In button1 Click you can do the following:

```
string newText = String.Format("<b>{0}</b>",textBox1.SelectedText);
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Replace(textBox1.SelectedText, newText);
```

I assume it is WinForms

Answer (score 0):

This is it mostly working http://jsfiddle.net/tx3Gr/

HTML

```
<div id="mytext">Hello There</div><button>click me</button>
```

Javascript: (with jquery)

```
function safe_tags(str) {
    return str.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;') ;
}

$('button').on('click',
function(){
        var txt = $('#mytext').text();

       var txt1= safe_tags('<b>'+txt+'</b>');

    $('#mytext').html(txt1)
});
```